# WebRTC failed after signing Android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webrtc, code-signing

The video streams between my PC and Android phone worked well without signing. After signing the Android app (for Google Play Store) with the key, WebRTC stopped working. What should I do to make it work with signing?

Comment: First, take a look at the logcat. Also, verify if the packageName (or applicationId) remains the same)

Comment: Check logs . If you are using proguard make sure you have not missed any rules for webRTC. Also make sure JNI is there in release build .

Comment: hmm..guys, I am using Cordova to build a hybrid app. Is there a way to obtain logs from the Android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem.

The problem was not with the signing. It was due to the changing of the temporary id after logging in, which prevented the peer from contacting the user. As the id was subsequently remembered and stored in localStorage, the problem only arose when the user first used the app and signed in.

Thank you for all your suggestions. Silly me...

Answer (score 0):

For Google Play App Signing there is a [helpful release checklist](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423).

Step 4 says:

If your app uses any API, you will usually need to register the certificate of the key Google signs your app with for authentication purposes. This is usually done through the fingerprint of the certificate.

To find the certificate of the key Google uses to re-sign your APK for delivery:

- Sign in to your Play Console.
- Select an app.
- On the left menu, click Release management > App signing.
- From this page, you can copy the most common fingerprints (MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256) of your app signing certificate. If the API provider requires a different type of fingerprint, you can also download the original certificate in DER format and run it through the transformation tools that the API provider requires.

I don't know what if any certificate checking your servers are doing, but I suspect this might be it.